# htaccess not working for port 443 ssl

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, apache2

I have configured ssl on port 443 for my site.. I have the same site on port 80 without http .. The problem is htaccess works fine on port 80 (without ssl) but doesn't work for https (port 443)

Here is my apache2 config

```
            <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                    DocumentRoot /home/SiteDir/
                    <Directory />
                            Options FollowSymLinks
                            AllowOverride All
                    </Directory>
                    <Directory /home/SiteDir/>
                            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                            AllowOverride All
                            Order allow,deny
                            allow from all
                    </Directory>
                     <Directory /home/SiteDir/mobile/>
                            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                            AllowOverride All
                            Order allow,deny
                            allow from all
                    </Directory>

                    #other SSL Code
                </VirtualHost>
            </IfModule>
```

Comment: The vhost for port 80 has `DocumentRoot /home/SiteDir/` also?

Comment: yes both have same DocumentRoot